# How to make thumbnails slide show only the thumbnails pic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make some simple JavaScript gallery with Thumbnail slider.

I made the slider and when I click on the left or the right arrow the margin-right change and add or remove 570px. But I want to make it better, and when the gallery loads, cancel the Scroll right option because there's actually pictures, the same also for last images.

HTML Structure look like this:

```
<div class="tumbNavigation">
    <div class="right_nav"></div>
    <div class="thumbnails">
        <div class="thumbnailsWrapper">
            <div class="thumbItem"></div>
            <div class="thumbItem"></div>
            <div class="thumbItem"></div>
            <div class="thumbItem"></div>
            <div class="thumbItem"></div>
            <div class="thumbItem"></div>
            <div class="thumbItem"></div>
            <div class="thumbItem"></div>
            <div class="thumbItem"></div>
            <div class="thumbItem"></div>
            <div class="thumbItem"></div>
            <div class="thumbItem"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left_nav"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code look like this:

```
        var pos = 0;
        var width = 570;
  $('.left_nav').click(function(){
        pos = pos - width;
        $('.thumbnailsWrapper').stop(true).animate({ marginRight: pos + "px"}, 500);
    });

  $('.right_nav').click(function(){

        pos = pos + width;
        $('.thumbnailsWrapper').stop(true).animate({ marginRight: pos + "px"}, 500);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, but there's no need to reinvent the wheel here. Carousels such as this are one of the most commonly developed widgets, so much so that you're bound to find something that's better, more stable, and has more features than anything you could quickly build. Here's a list of 55 carousel javascript plugins: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-carousel.html . I'm sure that one of them will work great for you, or it will be close enough that you can modify it to be perfect.

Comment: +1 because i was looking for some carousel scripts, and here they are grouped! THX:)